# Error while calling lua chunk: vim/_init_packages.lua:0: module 'vim.version' not found:

Tags: neovim, nvim-lspconfig

I've been trying to set up lsp for days now and I just can't understand why it isn't working. I have neovim version 0.9.1 so I should be good with the compatibility. The full error message is attached to the question as an image.

[screenshot of lspconfig error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhvSo.png)

**EXTRA INFO**
NVIM v0.9.1
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3

I tried to install lspconfig

Answer (score 2):

This can be caused by a mismatch between the `neovim` and `neovim-runtime`.

To find out which versions you have installed (for Ubuntu), run `apt list --installed | grep "neovim"`.

Response where the versions are the same:

```
neovim-runtime/focal,now 0.10.0~ubuntu1+git202306192018-72a6643b1-9b397864c-ed59f0191~ubuntu20.04.1 all [installed,automatic]
neovim/focal,now 0.10.0~ubuntu1+git202306192018-72a6643b1-9b397864c-ed59f0191~ubuntu20.04.1 amd64 [installed]
```

If the versions are not the same you need to remove Neovim and reinstall it.

Comment: This worked for me! I had to change the `/user/share/nvim` folder to the newer one.

Answer (score 1):

I just had to use snap.

`sudo snap install nvim --classic`

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is I updated the binary at location `which nvim`, but not the runtime files. I fixed it by:

- git cloning neovim
- checking out the tagged version that matches the binary `nvim -v`
- copied the runtime from the cloned neovim repo to `usr/share/nvim/runtime`

here's a bash script:

```
git clone https://github.com/neovim/neovim.git
cd neovim
git checkout v0.9.5
sudo cp -r runtime /usr/share/nvim/
```

Comment: This fixed mine as well. I copied the included share folder into an incorrect directory.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be the environment variables, like in my case $VIM and $VIMRUNTIME.

```
  moonflower  ~  nvim -v
NVIM v0.9.1
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3

   system vimrc file: "$VIM/sysinit.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/__w/neovim/neovim/build/nvim.AppDir/usr/share/nvim"

Run :checkhealth for more info
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34807927)